# Why isn't this obvious duplicate offered when asking the question

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

I just closed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016013/whats-the-difference-using-var-f-functiona-and-function-fa as an exact duplicate of [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname). This question was at the top of the **Related** list, so I was curious why the OP didn't notice it when he was asking the question.

So I tried asking the same question myself. The question I copied showed up at the top of the suggested questions, but the canonical question that everyone links to when closing as a duplicate was not anywhere on the list. In fact, none of the suggested questions seemed to be similar.

Comment: When I copied the post into the new question page, the duplicate is not in the "questions that may already have an answer" list at all.

Comment: seems kinda hard to look for duplicates with code in the title, especially when the function names are different `f` vs `functionName`

Comment: @Populus: The Related list found it just fine, so it seems the automatic dupe suggestions should find it too.

Comment: Instead of showing the questions ,maybe SO should show the answers.

Comment: @user2357112 To be fair, I think related gives lots of weight to questions with high votes. There are a handful of questions that are always at the top of questions with certain tags, like JS questions usually have the question about how closures work at the top, but it's only really related infrequently. So this was just one of the cases where the Related guess is right.

Comment: I think the problem is that you don't add tags until after writing the question body. If tags were added before or immediately after the title it would be easier to find suggested matches. As far as I know the "related" questions are generated after knowing which tags to match and the suggestions go on title alone.

Comment: The duplicate detector has no semantic skills. I always search the list when I'm asking a question, but several times I've had duplicates flagged that weren't in the list. And usually most of what is in the list has no connection whatsoever. Just happens to have a few words in. common.

Comment: @WesleyMurch When I did my test, I did it in the following order: title, tags, text. At neither stage did the best answer show up. All the suggested questions had only single digit votes, and some were a little negative.

Comment: I'm pretty sure only the title affects the suggestions. In my opinion this should be addressed, tags hugely affect the kind of answer you might be looking for.

Comment: @WesleyMurch I recall that tags are used to search for possible dupes, but only if you enter the tags first, and you normally don't cause it's at the bottom.

Comment: @JWLim I tried it and nothing happened, but what you say is true: tags are entered last (after the suggestions are shown and probably no longer visible). That's pretty much my point, and perhaps the reason for *"Why isn't this obvious duplicate offered when asking the question"*.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Hm, you seem to be correct. Tags don't seem to have any effect at all. I thought I read somewhere that they did. Yeah, I agree that tags should be used to search for dupes, and they probably should be entered first, too.

Comment: Seems to me like the suggestions are usually not even close, for example: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9zOyU.png ...and tag-based suggestions would be a big improvement.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Wow, it looks like it was mostly finding titles with "CAN" in them. Apparently spelling it with all caps causes the match to be weighted highly, even though the new question doesn't have it spelled that way.

Answer (score 4):

For the title `What's the difference using 'var f = function(a)' and 'function f(a)'?`
the [Lucene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene)-based textual similarity thingy returns results based on the relatively meaningless terms `What's`, `var` and even `f`.

Bad "more-like-this" results are a fact of life, as I [once answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21439187/604511) using Stack Overflow as an example.

IMO, it's an honest mistake. When I query Google, my choice of words and phrases may lead to a Stack Overflow post that was marked duplicate. I guess duplicate questions may serve as [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) by increasing the surface area of [SO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow) that is reachable from Google.

Comment: So, the score should be recalibrated. The weight of a word should be inversely proportional to its frequency.

Comment: I think that part of the issue here, is that the title consists only of very common words. It's difficult the "similarity thingy" to understand a question like that.

Comment: @Davidmh: the default Lucene scoring formula already discounts terms by their frequency in the index. Looks like it needs more aggressive stop word filtering.

Comment: @larsmans I admit I am not familiar with the algorithm, but it is clear they should be punished more.

Comment: In this case, improving the question title to use more English and less code would be a valid solution.